# How to run Airflow on a specific day_of_month at a certain time?

Tags: python, cron, scheduler, airflow

I am trying to run Airflow on the 2nd of every month at 11.00am, but I am failing to do so. My settings are:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': today_date,
    'email': ['mymail'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=7),
}

dag = DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='00 11 02 * *')
```

Airflow works flawlessly when I run a DAG on a daily basis:

```
schedule_interval='00 11 * * *'
```

but I don't seem to be able to make it work for a monthly basis :(

thanks!

Comment: i am not sure how it parses the cronlike strings, but i would try `0 11 2 * *` instead

Comment: I am afraid it did not work :(

Comment: What is your `today_date` here?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include that
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

today_date = datetime.today()

I don't think that's the issue, since I have that for all my other DAGs

Comment: I face the same problem (trying to run a DAG every week at 8 AM). My settings are `dag = DAG(dag_id='invalid_apis',default_args=args,schedule_interval='25 8 * * 0',catchup=False, 'start_date': days_ago(7))`. Weirdly, it runs if I try `dag = DAG(dag_id='invalid_apis',default_args=args,schedule_interval='25 8 * * 0-1',catchup=False, 'start_date': days_ago(7))` (but I think it is running the Sunday schedule.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run your dag on 2nd of every month at 11.00am. you can use this code.

```
schedule_interval = '0 11 2 * *'

dag_name = DAG(
    'DAG_ID',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
)
```

in the schedule interval 0 refers minute, 11 refers hour, 2 refers day of month, * refers any month, and next * refers any day of week.

for more scheduler Information check this website.
https://crontab.guru/#0_11_2_*_*

Answer (score 1):

In the comment you mention, that you use `datetime.today()` for `start_date` and that is exactly what's causing the problem. The job instance is started once the period it covers has ended, but in your case that will never happen. Try to adjust `start_date` to something like:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
start_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-1)
```

I suggest to re-read the [Scheduling & Triggers](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html) section in the documentation. I took me also a couple of time to get how to correctly schedule DAGs.

Comment: The FAQ also has some additional info on this as well, under ["What’s the deal with start_date?"](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date). Note that it does recommend against using dynamic values for `start_date`, so I suggest just hardcoding a date.

Comment: Yes, you are right but only if used with `catchup=False`.

Comment: I am afraid it did not work. I have tried doing what you said but the process did not start running either.

Weirdly enough, another process where:
today_date = datetime.today()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': today_date,
    'email': ['mymal'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='40 08 03 * *')

has triggered and is working now

Can you explain the "catchup" approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issue and discovered that my understanding of the airflow's `schedule_interval` as an *equivalent of* `cronjob` was wrong! It has same format, yes, but airflow triggers tasks differently than cronjob:

Airflow treats every run as an `data interval`, which starts at specified `schedule_interval` and ends before next run. **But** actual execution of the DAG run is performed on the `data interval`'s end! and for `schedule_interval = '@monthly'`.
For Example: your DAG, scheduled on 11:00 2.MM, e.g. having `execution_date=dt.datetime(YYYY,MM,2,11,0,0)` will actually be scheduled to run on `2.MM+1.YYYY 10:59:59`, e.g. at the end of your month.

(just wait patiently and see <strike>your code is working in a month</strike>  .
update: as mentioned above - since your `today_date` is dynamic, on every load of your DAG script, the execution timetable will be shifted one month ahead and it **never** actually runs! you need to use constants.)

> [DAG Runs - Data Interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.3/dag-run.html#data-interval)
>
> "All dates in Airflow are tied to the data interval concept in some way. The
> “logical date” (also called execution_date in Airflow versions prior
> to 2.2) of a DAG run, for example, **denotes the start of the data
> interval, not when the DAG is actually executed.**
>
> Similarly, since the start_date argument for the DAG and its tasks
> points to the same logical date, it marks the start of the DAG’s first
> data interval, not when tasks in the DAG will start running. In other
> words, **a DAG run will only be scheduled one interval after start_date.**"

See also: [Airflow Start_Date And Execution_Date Explained](https://infinitelambda.com/airflow-start-date-execution-date/)

So, if you want to run you DAG "today", you need to specify `'start_date': month_ago_date,` and if you use `execution_date` parameter, keep in mind it is equal to `data_interval_start`, not `data_interval_end` when the task is actually runs...